# Why aren't my nib files being created?

Tags: xcode, xib, nib

I've inherited a objective c application that I don't know much about.

My task was to change the login from a normal form view type thing, to a web view that gets content from a server. This all went fine and is implemented, but things weren't working right in the localized version.

Since there are no strings used, I deleted the localized files and now it seems my nib files don't get created. It's like there is a compiler error that's not reported. I checked the resource files in the build area, and it doesn't create nib files for anything after the login view I changed.

No errors are being reported during the build. I've tried re-starting Xcode, changing the branch in git to something without these changes. Nothing seems to clear up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across something like this. What finally worked for me was completely re-cloning the project from git. It appears that some of the files in the project were not tracked and just stayed around when I changed branches. I'm not sure if this is config related file, which we commonly don't track. All I know is that re-cloning fixed the issue.

In researching the problem, other common fixes include deleting and recreating offending xib files. Simply restarting Xcode. And, deleting a variety of other project related files and directories.

Hope this helps someone.